# How to make prestashop blockcart stay in same position?

Tags: css, prestashop

I have this issue with the Prestashop Theme... the position of the blockcart run off to bottom when i resize the browser... all browser seem to have problem except firefox was fine

Please tell me what code shall i add in css file to avoid the blockcart run to bottom when browser resize to smaller window.

## right_column

My website: http://goo.gl/TU2t7

```
#right_column {
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply set position property to fixed:

```
#right_column {
    ...
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: i added "position:fixed;" but the entire block move to left corner... i want the block stick in a same position even i do resizing on the same position.

Comment: its move from left to right corner... hmm... how to stick to same position that i having now?

Comment: `position: fixed;
left: 50%;
margin-left: 425px;`

Comment: Thanks.. its fixed crome & safari... but how to fix IE... still at the bottom